# Difference between python and c for loops

Tags: c, python-3.x

Why do the following `for` loops have different results:

**Python:**

```
for i in range(0,10):
    i=i-1
    print(i)
```

**Output:**
`-1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`

**C:**

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     {
      i=i-1;
      print("%d",i);
}
```

**Output:**
`infinite times -1`

Thank you.

Comment: Time to [learn how to debug your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Here some simple [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) would go a long way.

Comment: In python, `i` will always get a new value from `range(0,10)`, and doesn't matter what was the previous value. In c, you're incrementing or decrementing the value yourself, and it matters what was the previous value.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 - In C we declare a variable with data type,initiate it and then run upto some value with increment.
Some how Python deals with the same procedure but here we have to run a loop in the range

 Let me give you an example:
In c : Syntax

    for ( init; condition; increment ) {
       statement(s);
    }

    int i;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
```

1. This loop will run till the value of i becomes n.
2. In C++ you can also declare variable within the loop.
   In Python: Syntax:

   ```
       for iterating_var in sequence:
      statements(s)
   ```

   for x in range[1,11]

   - This loop will run till the value of x becomes 10.Note that we have to give upper range one more than upto which we have to execute our loop

Answer (score 0):

The `for in range` loop in case of Python doesn't update the variable `i` when it is changed within the code. This is because the loop is supposed to always iterate through the provided range.

In case of the C code, the loop changes the value of i with each iteration: `i=i-1` and the condition `i<10` always remains true.